# SSAS excessive partition scanning on 16+ members in set

Tags: ssas, mdx

SSAS 2012 scans all measure group partitions, if i put a set of more than 16 members on axis. 
If i put 15 or less, then only one partition is scanned.

To check this issue i created a very simple cube with Sales measure and Dates dimension.

Here is a sample query (it is dummy, so it just returns same "VAL" for each member in set on "1" axis):

```
with
member val as aggregate
             (
                [Dates].[Calendar].[DateId].&[20100101]:[Dates].[Calendar].[DateId].&[20100102],
                [Measures].[Amount]
             )
select 
        val on 0,
        head([Dates].[Calendar].[DateId].members, 16)  on 1
from [SSDDB]
```

The core feature he is AGGREGATE for 2 days (in real queries you could expect to see MTD instead of static range). Axis coordinates even don't seriously affect "val" member, they are just range of some dummy values.

When i run this query with **15** as **HEAD** function parameter, then i have following trace in profiler:

```
Started reading data from the 'Sales 2010' partition.
Finished reading data from the 'Sales 2010' partition.
```

and following **query subcube verbose**:

```
Dimension 1 [Dates] (+ * *)  [DateId]:+  [Years]:*  [Months]:*
```

But if a change **15** to **16** or more, then everything changes:

```
Started reading data from the 'Sales 2005' partition.
Started reading data from the 'Sales 2006' partition.
Started reading data from the 'Sales 2007' partition.
Started reading data from the 'Sales 2008' partition.
Started reading data from the 'Sales 2009' partition.
Started reading data from the 'Sales 2010' partition.
Finished reading data from the 'Sales 2007' partition.
Finished reading data from the 'Sales 2006' partition.
Started reading data from the 'Sales 2011' partition.
Finished reading data from the 'Sales 2005' partition.
Finished reading data from the 'Sales 2008' partition.
Finished reading data from the 'Sales 2009' partition.
Finished reading data from the 'Sales 2010' partition.
Finished reading data from the 'Sales 2011' partition.
```

and now "DateId" has "all" mark in verbose:

```
Dimension 1 [Dates] (* * *)  [DateId]:*  [Years]:*  [Months]:*
```

I tried to use:

1. Direct slice on partition: no changes
2. Static set of 16+ members: no changes
3. Change aggregate to sum: no changes
4. Cut aggregate's set to 1 member: it works ok, but who needs such aggregate...
5. Checked DATAID: all are sequental, no gaps, no overlaps

When aggregate-function is SUM - not a big deal, but DISTINCT COUNT makes all queries run 3 times longer. This is a performance killer when you click on "+" button in EXCEL, and want to see MTD (distinct-count measure) for each day in a month.

Any ideas how to stop excessive scanning?